# setting dynamic height for kendo ListView

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-listview

Is there anyway I can set dynamic height for kendo listview and skeletoncontainer? height is not adjusting based on the screen size.

layout.cshtml

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - IDOH Job Bank</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/css")
    <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/themes/6.4.0/default/default-ocean-blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.kendostatic.com/2023.2.606/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.kendostatic.com/2023.2.606/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.kendostatic.com/2023.2.606/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.kendostatic.com/2023.2.606/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
</head>
<body class="k-content">
    <div class="navbar navbar-dark in-bg-color fixed-top navbar-expand-md">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <header class="header">
                <div class="header-container">
                    <div class="agencyrow row expanded align-middle top-menu">
                        <div class="expanded columns top-menu-agency" style="padding:0px;">
                            <nav class="in-bg-color">
                                <ul class="menu expanded top-menu-agency-menu text-center">
                                    <li class="agency-link" id="agency-brand">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <div id="agency-brand-wrap" title="Indiana Department of Health">
                                                <span id="agency-logo">
                                                    <img src="~/Content/LDF/Images/IDH-Logo-Shield-White_Transparent.png" alt="Indiana Department of Health Logo">
                                                </span>
                                                <span id="agency-name">IDOH Job Bank</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid body-content pt-3 mt-3">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid body-content pt-3 mt-3" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;width:100%">
        <footer>
            <div align="center" style="font-size:small" class="pt-5">
                <hr />
                <p>&copy;COPYRIGHT @DateTime.Now.Year , INDIANA STATE DEPARTMENT OF HEALTH, ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#responsive-panel").kendoResponsivePanel({
                breakpoint: 768,
                autoClose: false,
                orientation: "top"
            });
        });
        function onclick(e) {
            $("#responsive-panel").getKendoResponsivePanel().toggle();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
<style>
    .in-bg-color {
        background-color: #112A6D !important;
    }

    .activeTab {
        background-color: #cc7027;
    }

    .Header {
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .Content {
        padding: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 80px;
    }

    #wrapper {
        position: relative;
    }

    .navbar-nav > li {
        padding-left: 12px;
        padding-right: 12px;
    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .modal {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .modal-dialog {
        text-align: left; /* you'll likely want this */
        max-width: 60%;
        width: auto !important;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .myTooltip,
    .myTooltip .k-tooltip-content {
        color: #2a2828;
        background: none !important;
        background-color: transparent !important;
        border: none !important;
    }

    .myTooltip .k-callout,
    .myTooltip .k-callout-w {
        border: none !important;
    }

    [data-toggle="collapse"] .fa:before {
        content: "\f139";
    }

    [data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed .fa:before {
        content: "\f13a";
    }

    .wide {
        width: 75%;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    .wide1 {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .wide2 {
        float: left;
    }

    .wide10 {
        align-content: flex-start;
    }

    .alignation {
        width: 600px;
    }

    .layout-example .aui-item p {
        background-color: white;
    }

    .required:before {
        content: "*";
        font-weight: bold;
        color: red;
    }

    * {
        font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 10pt;
    }

    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .modal-dialog-centered {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: calc(100% - (.5rem * 2));
    }

    .custom-validation-summary li {
        list-style-type: circle;
        color: red;
    }

    .aui-flatpack-example {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 3px;
        margin: 0px 0 5px 0;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .EmpSearchInfo {
        /*width: 20%;*/
    }

    .vcard {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 555px;
    }

    .vcard td {
        padding: 2px 2px 2px 5px;
        margin: 0;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }

    .vcard th {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: #000;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 2px 2px 2px 5px;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: left;
    }

    legend, label {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    a {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    table#gvResults {
        background: #FFFFFF;
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    .template-item {
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
    }

    li.k-item {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .k-dropdown {
        width: auto;
    }
    .row {
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-right: -15px;
        margin-left: -15px;
    }
</style>
```

job.cshtml

```
<div>
 <form style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;">
     <div class="row">
         @*<div class="col-md-1">
         </div>*@
         <div class="col-md-2">
             @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.JobTitle, new SelectList(
                     Model.ddlTitles, "Id", "Name", 0), "Select Title", new { @class = "form-control" })*@
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
             @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.countyName, new SelectList(
                                                         Model.ddlCounties, "Id", "Name", 0), "Select County", new { @class = "form-control" })
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
             @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.jobType, new SelectList(
                                                         Model.ddlJobTypes, "Id", "Name", 0), "Select JobType", new { @class = "form-control" })
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
             <input type="button" name="Search" value="Search" style="text-align:center;" class="btn btn-info" id="btnSubmit">
             <input type="button" name="Clear" value="Clear" style="text-align:center;" class="btn btn-info" id="btnClear">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
             @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.divName, new SelectList(
                     Model.ddlDivisions, "Id", "Name", 0), "Select Division", new { @class = "form-control" })*@
         </div>
     </div>
 </form>
</div>

<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="leftTemplate">
 <div class="product">
     <P style="font-size:medium; font-weight: bold">#:Title#</P>

     <p style="margin: 0px 0px 5px;"> Posted Date : #: kendo.toString(PostDate, "MM/dd/yyyy")#  |  Positions Available : #= Vacancies #  |  County : #= County #</p>
     @*<p style="margin: 0px 0px 5px;"> Positions Available : #= Vacancies # </p>
     <p style="margin: 0px 0px 5px;"> County : #= County # </p>*@
     <hr>
     <p>#= JobDesc #</p>
 </div>
</script>

<script>
 function onChange(e) {
     var selected = e.sender.select();
     var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(selected[0])
     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url:"@Url.Action("GetCard","User")",
         data: { id: dataItem.ID },
         success: function (viewHTML) {
             $("#skeleton").hide();
             $(".selected-item").html(viewHTML);
         },
         error: function (errorData) { console.log(errorData) }
     });
 }
 function onDataBound(e) {
     // get a reference to the ListView widget
     var listView = $("#jobsListView").data("kendoListView");
     console.log(listView.content);
     listView.select(listView.content.children().first());
 }
 function searchCriteria() {
     return {
         //JobTitle: $("#JobTitle").val(),
         countyName: $("#countyName").val(),
         jobType: $("#jobType").val(),
         //divName: $("#divName").val()
     };
 }

 $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
     $("#jobsListView").data("kendoListView").dataSource.read();
 });

 $("#btnClear").click(function () {
     $("#JobTitle").val('');
     $("#countyName").val('');
     $("#jobType").val('');
     $("#divName").val('');
     $("#jobsListView").data("kendoListView").dataSource.read();
 });
</script>

<div class="parent">
 <div class="demo-section narrow">
     @(Html.Kendo().ListView<IDOHJobBank.Data.Models.UserJobDetails>()
         .Name("jobsListView")
         .TagName("div")
         .ClientTemplateId("leftTemplate")
         .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
             .PageSize(10)
             .Model(m =>
             {
                 m.Id(f => f.ID);
             }
             )
             .Read(read => read.Action("Jobs_Read", "User").Data("searchCriteria"))
         )
         .Scrollable()
         .Pageable()
         .Selectable(s => s.Mode(ListViewSelectionMode.Single))
         .Events(e => { e.Change("onChange"); e.DataBound("onDataBound"); })
     )
 </div>

 <div class="selected-item" style="display:block;">
     @(Html.Kendo().SkeletonContainer()
         .Name("skeleton")
         .Animation(SkeletonContainerAnimation.Pulse)
         .Template(
             "<div class='k-card'>" +
                 "<div class='k-card-header'>" +
                     "<div>" +
                         "<span data-shape-circle class='k-card-image avatar'></span>" +
                     "</div>" +
                     "<div class='user-info' style='width: 100%;'>" +
                         "<span data-shape-text class='k-card-title'></span>" +
                         "<span data-shape-text class='k-card-subtitle' style='width: 35%;'></span>" +
                     "</div>" +
                 "</div>" +
                 "<span data-shape-rectangle style='width: 800px; height: 660px; '></span>" +
                     "<div class='k-card-body'>" +
                             "<span data-shape-text></span>" +
                         "</div>" +
                     "</div>"+
             "</div>")
     )
 </div>
</div>

<style>
 .container-fluid {
     display: block;
 }

 .parent {
     display: flex;
 }

 .parent > div {
     display: inline-block;
 }

 .narrow {
     width: 35%;
 }

 .narrow > .k-pager {
     border-color: transparent;
     background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
 }

 .k-listview {
     border-color: transparent;
 }

 .selected-item {
     padding: 10px 5px;
 }

 .card {
     width: 60%;
     height: 80%;
 }

 #jobsListView {
     padding: 10px 5px;
     margin-bottom: -1px;
     min-height: 680px;
     height: auto !important;
     /* Avoid cutout if font or line is bigger */
     font: inherit;
 }

 .product {
     float: left;
     position: relative;
     width: 95%;
     height: auto !important;
     margin: 0 5px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     padding: 5px;
     border: 0.5px solid grey;
     border-radius: 5px;
 }

 .product img {
     width: 150px;
     height: 150px;
 }

 .product h3 {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 3px 5px 0 0;
     max-width: 96px;
     overflow: hidden;
     line-height: 1.1em;
     font-size: .9em;
     font-weight: normal;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     color: black;
 }

 .main-image {
     width: 180px;
     height: 180px;
 }

 .k-listview:after {
     content: ".";
     display: block;
     height: 0;
     clear: both;
     visibility: hidden;
 }

 .scrollable {
     overflow-y: auto;
     max-height: 400px;
 }

 .k-card {
     border-radius: 6px;
     border-width: 1px;
     border-style: solid;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     outline: 0;
     font-family: inherit;
     font-size: 14px;
     line-height: 1.4285714286;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     position: fixed;
     overflow: hidden;
     -webkit-touch-callout: none;
     -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 }

 .k-textbox, .k-textbox > input {
     font-size: 100%;
     font-family: inherit;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 1px;
     -webkit-appearance: none
 }
</style>
```